# R spatial object and rbuffer from rgeos

Tags: r

I have an issue with the `rbuffer` tool from the `rgeos` package.

I have a spatial point object called `city` which includes the following information on ~200 cities:

```
ID   Latitude   Longitude    Name
1    30.044420  31.235712    Cairo
2    -1.292066  36.821946    Nairobi
```

Around each city I want to create a buffer of 5000km. I wanted to use the `rbuffer` function from the `rgeos` package.

```
City_Buff <- gBuffer(city, width=5000, byid=TRUE)
plot(City_Buff)
```

All my layers are defined using the following coordinate system:

```
CRS("+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs")
```

As I have numerous cities and I want every city to be treated on their own (so they all get their own buffer), I use the `byid=True` statement. 
First of all, is this how it should be used considering my problem?
Secondly, when I plot my buffer I just see one circles instead of the 200 I would expect. Am I missing something on this?

Comment: Apparently it seems that although I defined all my layers in the above-mentioned CRS, I can just use degrees in the gBuffer width statement. Anyone has an idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem is, that when importing the input file into R, the wrong CRS was assigned. If that is corrected, the buffer works in meters again.